# How can I find the correct mtrace script to interpret mtrace output?

Tags: c, linux, mtrace

I'm using the gnu mtrace tool to check for memory leaks in C code. This generates a difficult-to-read text file (presumably a log of all dynamic memory operations) that can be interpreted by a perl script also called mtrace.

I've tried using mtrace script version 2.15, but that doesn't seem to work properly, reporting the same memory addresses as being both freed but not allocated *and* allocated but not freed.
Maybe it doesn't match the text file format (the text file doesn't have a version number).
I tried versions 2.5.and 2.7, which won't run seemingly due to obsolete perl syntax (running perl v5.10.1).

Anyone had similar problems and resolved them?

Answer (score 1):

I think the mtrace script v2.15 is fine.
The memory addresses reported as being freed without being allocated were being freed *before* they were re-used, with the subsequent allocation semi-coincidentally using the same addresses. In fact they had originally been allocated before I started mtrace.